# slow sql with left-join / subquery (100.000 records)

Tags: sql, mysql, subquery, left-join, query-optimization

I have a multilingual website with an implemented game search and sorting function (I deleted the last question because there was a lot of unnecessary information in it; and yes, instead of "books" now "games" because I created a new test database). The search is carried out by the following query:

```
SELECT games.id AS id 
FROM games 
LEFT JOIN games_titles ON games.id = games_titles.game_id 
WHERE 1
  AND EXISTS (SELECT games_devs.game_id 
              FROM games_devs
              WHERE games_devs.game_id = games.id 
                AND games_devs.dev IN (...))
  AND EXISTS (SELECT games_publishers.game_id 
              FROM games_publishers 
              WHERE games_publishers.game_id = games.id 
                AND games_publishers.publisher IN (...))
  AND games_titles.lang=1
ORDER BY games_titles.title
```

The request is triggered for more than 2.5 seconds, without ORDER BY - more than 1 second. There may be several more parameters in the search condition, because I accept them from the post request and convert them into a string. But the essence is the same. Now there are 100,000 records in the database, filters work very slowly. The operation is performed quickly only when there are no subqueries and joins. Here is more detailed information (all fields that are used in ON and WHERE are indexed using BTREE):

EXPLAIN (without alphabetical sorting):

```
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+
| id | select_type  | table            | type   | possible_keys            | key          | key_len | ref                                | rows  |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | games_titles     | ref    | game_id_index,lang_index | lang_index   | 4       | const                              | 98995 |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | games            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY      | 4       | test_db.games_titles.game_id       | 1     |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2>      | eq_ref | distinct_key             | distinct_key | 4       | func                               | 1     |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery3>      | eq_ref | distinct_key             | distinct_key | 4       | func                               | 1     |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | games_devs       | ALL    | game_id_index            | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                               | 98437 |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+
|  3 | MATERIALIZED | games_publishers | ALL    | game_id_index            | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                               | 98437 |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+
```

profiling (without alphabetical sorting):

```
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 1  | Starting               | 168 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 2  | Checking Permissions   |  21 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 3  | Opening Tables         |  81 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 4  | After Opening Tables   |  25 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 5  | System Lock            |  15 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 6  | Table Lock             |  17 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 7  | Init                   |  78 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 8  | Optimizing             |  93 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 9  | Statistics             | 174 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 10 | Preparing              | 132 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 11 | Executing              |  15 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 12 | Sending Data           |  1,4 s |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 13 | End Of Update Loop     |  26 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 14 | Removing Tmp Table     |  15 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 15 | End Of Update Loop     |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 16 | Removing Tmp Table     |  11 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 17 | End Of Update Loop     |  10 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 18 | Query End              |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 19 | Commit                 |  11 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 20 | Closing Tables         |  10 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 21 | Unlocking Tables       |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 22 | Closing Tables         |  18 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 23 | Starting Cleanup       |   9 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 24 | Freeing Items          |  21 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 25 | Updating Status        |  69 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 26 | Reset For Next Command |  19 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
```

EXPLAIN (with sorting):

```
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table            | type   | possible_keys            | key          | key_len | ref                                | rows  | Extra                       |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | games_titles     | ref    | game_id_index,lang_index | lang_index   | 4       | const                              | 98995 | Using where; Using filesort |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | games            | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY      | 4       | test_db.games_titles.game_id       | 1     | Using where; Using index    |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery2>      | eq_ref | distinct_key             | distinct_key | 4       | func                               | 1     | Using where                 |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | <subquery3>      | eq_ref | distinct_key             | distinct_key | 4       | func                               | 1     | Using where                 |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | games_devs       | ALL    | game_id_index            | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                               | 98437 | Using where                 |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
|  3 | MATERIALIZED | games_publishers | ALL    | game_id_index            | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                               | 98437 | Using where                 |
+----+--------------+------------------+--------+--------------------------+--------------+---------+------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------+
```

profiling (with sorting):

```
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 1  | Starting               | 199 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 2  | Checking Permissions   | 101 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 3  | Opening Tables         |  56 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 4  | After Opening Tables   |  18 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 5  | System Lock            |  27 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 6  | Table Lock             |  18 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 7  | Init                   |  94 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 8  | Optimizing             | 211 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 9  | Statistics             | 417 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 10 | Preparing              | 138 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 11 | Sorting Result         |  35 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 12 | Executing              |  13 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 13 | Sending Data           |  18 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 14 | Creating Sort Index    |  2,4 s |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 15 | End Of Update Loop     |  35 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 16 | Removing Tmp Table     |  23 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 17 | End Of Update Loop     |  12 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 18 | Removing Tmp Table     |  15 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 19 | End Of Update Loop     |  14 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 20 | Query End              |  12 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 21 | Commit                 |  15 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 22 | Closing Tables         |  14 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 23 | Unlocking Tables       |  12 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 24 | Closing Tables         |  30 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 25 | Starting Cleanup       |  17 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 26 | Freeing Items          |  32 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 27 | Updating Status        | 185 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
| 28 | Reset For Next Command |  48 µs |
+----+------------------------+--------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `games` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rating` double NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `img` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `img_type` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `rating_index` (`rating`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `date_index` (`date`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=326678 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `games_titles` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_id_index` (`game_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lang_index` (`lang`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=652865 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `games_descriptions` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lang` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `desc_index` (`description`(1024)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `lang_index` (`lang`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=253401 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `games_devs` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `dev` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_id_index` (`game_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=126699 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `games_publishers` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_id_index` (`game_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=126696 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `games_genres` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `genre_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_id_index` (`game_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `genre_id_index` (`genre_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=121601 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `games_times` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `time_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_id_index` (`game_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `time_id_index` (`time_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=126684 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci

CREATE TABLE `games_statuses` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `status_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_id_index` (`game_id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `status_id_index` (`status_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=326387 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

I tried to make an auxiliary table "games_search", in which there were columns game_id, attributes (a text record of all attributes of the game to search for it via LIKE), but this option also did not fit, because there was no gain in speed, and alphabetical sorting is still needed, so without combining tables here definitely not enough. Please tell me what is the best way for me to do / which architecture is better to use to get rid of poor performance? I'm afraid to imagine what will happen on 1 million records

Comment: Hi - please don't link to images. Add all relevant information directly to your question as editable text

Comment: Also your "AND games_titles.lang=1" is effectively turning your LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN so it would be more performant to use an INNER join

Comment: I would try a combination of one or more composite indexes and see how they impact performance. 1) games_titles (game_id, lang) 2) games_devs (game_id, dev) 3) games_publishers (game_id, publisher)

Comment: @NickW okay I will try. maybe add the "title" field from ORDER to the composite index?

Comment: I doubt that will help but feel free to try

Comment: Hmm, it started to work a little faster.. But still quite a long time. Moreover, a live search, I don’t want to mask all this with loading animation.

Comment: Get rid of the Auto_increment on the many-to-many tables and add 2 indexes as indicated here: [_Many-to-many_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)

Comment: @RickJames, after deleting the "id" in the child tables, it began to work faster, 1.5-2 second. Tell me where to put the indexes? The documentation at the link, as I understand it, describes a slightly different situation.

Comment: By the way (the problem has not been completely solved yet), by replacing "SELECT table.game_id" in the subquery with "SELECT 1", I got a pretty good increase in performance.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: How many items in the IN(...) lists?  (1 vs a few vs lots -- may make a difference)

Comment: @RickJames - oh sorry, I don't use the IN operator for "games_devs" and "games_publishers" (because I filter "games_genres", "games_statuses" and "games_times" with it). It is necessary, probably, to make through full-text search? There can be about 20 elements in genres, only 4 statuses, and only 2 times (maximum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `games_devs` (
  `id` int(50) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `dev` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `game_id_index` (`game_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=126699 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci
```

-->

```
CREATE TABLE `NEW_games_devs` (
  `game_id` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `dev` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (game_id, dev),
  KEY  (dev, `game_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=126699 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
```

And here's a way to achieve the conversion:

```
INSERT INTO NEW_games_devs
    SELECT game_id, dev
        FROM games_devs;

RENAME TABLE games_devs TO OLD_games_devs,
             NEW_games_devs TO games_devs ;

DROP TABLE OLD_games_devs;
```

Comment: I so understood, for other tables to do the same? Is there any change in the index if the "lang" field is present?

Comment: for example, "title" is not "primary", because there may be 2 entries with different "lang"

Comment: @MarkUuy - Before I answer your question, please decide whether a game in two different langs is one "game" or two.  That is, is `lang` really part of game_id or not.

Comment: The same game with the name in two or more different languages ​​is the same object. Regardless of whether there is a variation of any of the attributes specifically for this language, I create an entry in the database (just if the field is empty, the default option will be there - in English). That is, the game_id from the child tables refers to the same game. "PRIMARY KEY" does not give me the ability to add an entry to the table with the same name, for example.

Comment: `PRIMARY KEY(game_name, lang)`

Comment: is this the only key to be set in the table? By the way, I saw somewhere that a field from "ORDER" is added to composite indexes to achieve good performance. Should I use it in my case?

Comment: @MarkUuy - The PK is a special index; it is unique, it orders the data, and it is the only way to get to the full row.  Non-`UNIQUE` `INDEXes` can have extra columns _from the same table_ tacked on to make that `INDEX` "covering", or to at leas _maybe_ avoid a sort needed by `ORDER BY`.  Which `SELECT` are you referring to?  More:  [_Index Cookbook_](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: perhaps you meant to ask about "ORDER" and not "SELECT"? I mean a query involving sorting by "game_title". Do I need to add a field from "ORDER" to the composite index to make the operation run faster? I just didn't understand a little... Will the key that you advised me above be the only one in the table or are there any others? That's what I wanted to know

Comment: Can a game ever be missing a title?  If not `LEFT` should be removed.  (Then we can further discuss `ORDER BY`.)

Comment: No, the title is always present. I did a LEFT-JOIN when fields for other languages ​​weren't populated with a default value. But now it can be removed.

Comment: @MarkUuy - Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` both before and after removing `LEFT`.  I _think_ they will be different, and the plain `JOIN` _may_ run faster.

Comment: ok, I'll compare these options. But I still would like to know, is the key (which you advised above) the only one that needs to be set in the games_titles table? Or do you need some other information to answer? I did not understand a little, we left the question in the direction of JOINs. Do I need to add a composite index to optimize ORDER or ```PRIMARY KEY(game_title, lang)``` the only key in the table?

Comment: If there is one row per game-lang pair, then that would be a good PK.  You _may_ want another table that ties the various lang-versions of games together.  The indexes (including the PK) are derived from the queries that you will be running.

Comment: But after all, PK does not allow creating records with the same title in the table (if the option for some language is set by default). If it's not difficult for you, please write what you mean (mb edit your answer).

Comment: @MarkUuy Re ( "title" is not "primary) -- Change these 2 tables:  `games_devs` and `games_publishers`.

Comment: in games_statuses, games_genres and games_times should I set the same indexes? And do you need any additional keys for full-text search on the columns "dev" and "publisher"?

Comment: In `games_titles`, change "KEY `lang_index` (`lang`) USING BTREE" to `KEY(lang, title)`.  That is likely to help your original query somewhat.

Comment: do I need a full-text index to search by developer and publisher? (in the example of my question, I do it through the IN operator, but in fact it's not, I just made a mistake).

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. for the tables.  I need to see at least the diata type for `dev`.

Comment: "SHOW CREATE TABLE" I took from your answer. In general, I tried the index (lang, title) and did not see a special increase in performance. It's still working slowly. Only queries where there is a condition for sampling from dev are triggered quickly, which is logical, because the search area narrows down to one condition.

Comment: The subqueries are the slow part.  That hides any improvement that `(lang, title)` provides.

Comment: should I use JOIN instead of subquery?

Comment: After you have changed the indexes on both `games_dev` and `games_publishers`, provide a new `EXPLAIN`.